# Save calculated records on non-calculated datasource

Tags: google-app-maker

First of all, really sorry for my english, I'll try to be as clear as possible. From the client I set query parameters of a datasource in a calculated model and reload the datasource. The query script call a server script that create new records for the calculted datasource. At the end I have data correctly displayed on a chart widget. Now I would like to save this data permanently in a non calculated model. Which is the best way ? I've tried to run a server script then create calculated records again, read and save all them in the non-calculated model, but in this way I created the calculated records twice, and it's not so efficient. Unfortunatly is not possible to pass items that I display on chart to server script, so which is a better ways?